# Geotools 12.3 - Create DataStore from WFS Service ArcGIS Server

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I'm trying to create a DataStore in Java with Geotools 12.3. 
With WFS services in geoserver works fine, but with WFS services in ArcGIS doesn't work at all.

This is the exception:

```
WARNING [net.refractions.xsi.element] (default task-78) Starting schema with ServiceExceptionReport element.
ERROR [stderr] (default task-78) java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR [stderr] (default task-78)    at org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.WFS_1_0_0_DataStore.getSchema(WFS_1_0_0_DataStore.java:368)
ERROR [stderr] (default task-78)    at org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.WFSFeatureSource.getSchema(WFSFeatureSource.java:204)
```

This is my Java code:
"Main Class"

```
public String getDataSelection(String url) throws IOException {

    Map mapResponse = new HashMap();
    String response = null;

    double x1 = strToDbl(this.getBboxT()[0]);
    double y1 = strToDbl(this.getBboxT()[1]);
    double x2 = strToDbl(this.getBboxT()[2]);
    double y2 = strToDbl(this.getBboxT()[3]);

    try {

        String url = "http://sigserv02.anla.gov.co:6080/arcgis/services/Alertas_tempranas_deforestacion/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities";
        int layerName = 0;
        DataStore ds = configWFSDataStore(url);

        FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
        FeatureSource fs = ds.getFeatureSource(layerName);
        FeatureType schema = fs.getSchema();
        CoordinateReferenceSystem worldCRS = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
        String geometryPropertyName = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
        ReferencedEnvelope click = new ReferencedEnvelope(x1,x2, y1, y2, worldCRS);

        ReferencedEnvelope bbox = click.transform(targetCRS, true);
        Polygon clickPolygon = JTS.toGeometry(bbox);
        Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property(geometryPropertyName), ff.literal(clickPolygon));

        Query query = new Query(layerName, filter);
        query.setMaxFeatures(1500);

        FeatureReader<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = ds.getFeatureReader(query, Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT);

        CoordinateReferenceSystem CRSobjetivo = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

        if(source.hasNext()){
            .......
        }
        else{
            response = "empty";
        }
    } catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        ..........
    }
    return response;
}
```

configWFSDataStore Method:

```
 public static DataStore configWFSDataStore(String url) throws IOException {
    DataStore dataStore = null;

    BBConectionWFS conectionWFS = new BBConectionWFS();
    conectionWFS.setGetCapabilities(url+"service=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities");
    dataStore = conectionWFS.dataStoreWFS();

    return dataStore;
}
```

BBConectionWFS Class:

```
public DataStore dataStoreWFS() {
    DataStore dataStore = null;
    try {

        Map<String, String> connectionParameters;
        String getCapabilities = "http://sigserv02.anla.gov.co:6080/arcgis/services/Alertas_tempranas_deforestacion/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities";

        String variableCapabilities = "WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL";
        connectionParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        connectionParameters.put(variableCapabilities, getCapabilities);

        dataStore = (new WFSDataStoreFactory()).createDataStore(connectionParameters);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataStore;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoTools 12 is a really old version and the WFS system has been completely rewritten since then so I would upgrade. Your code works fine with GeoTools 20 on my machine. The following gives a result of `Alertas_tempranas_deforestacion:Alertas_Tempranas_Deforestacion` which matches QGIS' view of it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory;

public class EsriWFS {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EsriWFS me = new EsriWFS();
    DataStore ds = me.dataStoreWFS();
    for (String n:ds.getTypeNames()) {
      System.out.println(n);
    }
  }

  public DataStore dataStoreWFS() {
    DataStore dataStore = null;
    try {

        Map<String, Serializable> connectionParameters = new HashMap<>();
        String getCapabilities = "http://sigserv02.anla.gov.co:6080/arcgis/services/Alertas_tempranas_deforestacion/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities";

        String variableCapabilities = "WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL";


        connectionParameters.put(variableCapabilities, getCapabilities);

        dataStore = (new WFSDataStoreFactory()).createDataStore(connectionParameters);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataStore;
}
}
```

Comment: Update the version of the GeoTools to 19.1 but the problem persists, I post the full version of my code

Comment: does my code work for you? just as a test?